# Recompile .NET 2.0 UserControl Library in 3.5?

Tags: winforms, user-controls

A set of UserControls I've developed for in-house use were written in .NET 2.0 but my current development is in .NET 3.5.  Assuming the following:

- no need to update these controls in my 2.0 projects
- there are no 3.5 features I need in my library

Is there any advantage at all (beyond satisfying a misplaced sense of tidyness) for me to update my control library to 3.5?

I believe even if a machine using my controls doesn't have the .NET 2.0 runtime installed, my library will run fine if it has the 3.5 runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason to bring them to 3.5 would be the tidiness concern. Otherwise they will work just fine with .NET 3.5 in every other aspect. Keep in mind that 3.0 and 3.5 were library extensions to 2.0. I.e. They run top of 2.0. (Things changed with 4.0 however.)

Comment: +1 for "they run on top of 2.0", that they don't is the top misconception around 3.*